# Phonegap: Save a photo to a specific path

Tags: plugins, cordova

I'm using cordova framework to develop applications on iOS.
I need to save a photo (just taken) in a specific path, but cordova default sets it to localhost/var/mobile/Applications/.../tmp/cdv_photo_006.jpg while I want to save it in .../www/data/camera/cdv_photo_006.jpg
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

in IOS you have just just access to your app bundle(temp + document folder) at least in non-jailbreak iphone's and ipad's , so what you are doing is impossible.